# Hubspot File Uploading using PHP-Hubspot API

Tags: javascript, php, hubspot

I have been using Hubspot for my client for Inbound Marketing and Email Campaigns. I have managed forms,email templates,workflows etc in hubspot using its PHP api. Now I am in need to upload a file using Hubspot.

Currently I'm following the method mentioned here(following PHP example)

http://developers.hubspot.com/docs/methods/forms/submit_form

I would like to have a file upload button along with other fields. While searching for a solution, i saw this:

http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/Can-I-add-a-File-Upload-field-to-my-forms

Following the step described there, i was able to add a file upload button, but when i checked the submissions, no upload details are there.

Can any one guide me how to implement this in a  PHP / javascript environment.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps your uploads have been successful but you're not looking in the right place for them?  Form uploads on Hubspot are stored with the contact and not with the submission entries.  You can follow these instructions to find them:

1. Navigate to Contacts > Contacts Home
2. Search for the name of the contact whose file you want to retrieve > click the name to open the contact record
3. Click Properties on the left-hand side of the page
4. Locate the appropriate file upload property
5. Click the button next to the property (looks like a box with an arrow in it) > your file will open

Instructions from:  http://help.hubspot.com/articles/KCS_Article/Contacts/How-do-I-find-the-file-that-my-contact-uploaded-with-a-form-submission

If I am mistaken, then perhaps you can post your form's HTML code?

Comment: What I'm doing is that I'm migrating emails from superoffice and try to upload the attachments for the emails. I see the files when looking at the mails under activity for a contact. But nowhere else.